# OpenSSH Library not found (Issues with Conda perhaps?)

Tags: macos, terminal, openssl, package, conda

I am trying to install a package on my Mac. The installation always fails with the following error line : OpenSSL library was not found in your system. Now, if I type

```
openssl version -a
```

This is the output I get

```
built on: Mon Feb 10 17:07:46 2020 UTC
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3/include -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9628f99a-6ef8-4f2c-49be-ff8c4ad85bd7/volume/openssl_1581354377010/work=/usr/local/src/conda/openssl-1.1.1d -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -fPIC -arch x86_64 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9628f99a-6ef8-4f2c-49be-ff8c4ad85bd7/volume/openssl_1581354377010/work=/usr/local/src/conda/openssl-1.1.1d -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3/include
OPENSSLDIR: "/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/Users/kshitij/opt/anaconda3/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

I understand that anaconda might be bugging with me, so I have tried

```
conda deactivate
```

Now if I try the same thing I get :

```
LibreSSL 2.8.3
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"
```

But if I now try installing the package, I still get the same error line. So I am very unsure what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to compile something? Not sure what comes with the `openssl` Conda package, but the dynamic libraries may not be automatically included on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH or other linker-specific search paths.

Comment: Yes I am trying to compile a open sourced package I downloaded off of Github. I do think somehow the paths are causing issue, but I do not have much practical experience with dealing with them. I literally compile this package in a folder on the desktop. So if you have any suggestions on how to include the openssl in this path, that would be very helpful

Comment: In that case, show us the steps to get the error (edit the question). The output from `openssl version -a` is irrelevant - compilers don't link against the CLI. For `ld` linker, locate the `lib/` folder that has `libopenssl` in it and either add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or add it to the compilation command. If using Conda, using the `conda-forge::compilers` package automatically manages the lib paths.